# What happens to t-statistic in log transformation of linear regression?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, linear-regression

**Problem**

Suppose that the logarithm of $Y$ is regressed on the logarithm of $X$, the fitted regression
being:

$$log \hat{Y} = \hat{\beta_1} + \hat{\beta_2} log X$$
Suppose $X^* = \mu X$, where $\mu$ is a constant, and suppose that $ log Y$ is regressed on log $X^*$
.
Determine how the regression coefficients are related to those of the original regression.
Determine also how the t statistic for $\hat{\beta_2}$ and $R^2$
for the equation are related to those in the
original regression.

**My ideas:**
We can substitute the $X^* = \mu X$ into the original regression and get that $log \hat{Y} = \hat{\beta_1} + \hat{\beta_2}log \mu + \hat{\beta_2}log X$. As $\mu$ is a constant the regression we stay the same, with exception of new intercept $\hat{\beta} := \hat{\beta_1} + \hat{\beta_2}log \mu $.

Also, as t-statistics is $t = \frac{\hat{\beta_2} - \beta_2}{s.e(\hat{\beta_2})}$, it seems that $t_{\text{stat}}$ will increase in $\mu$ times as $ s.e(\hat{\beta_2})$ decrease in $\mu$ times.

Can it somehow help me?

Comment: what is the 'original regression'? Is it $Y$ regressed on $X$, or $\log Y$ regressed on $\log X$?

Comment: @dimebucker It's the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right. The only thing, yo should've substituted $X = \frac{X^*}{\mu}$. As you correctly mentioned the slope coefficient stays the same. However, new intercept is $\hat{\beta_1} - \hat{\beta_2}log\mu$.
You may check that resiaduals for the original and new models are the same. Hence, RSS and $R^2$ stay unchanged.